# How to implement app communication port

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Saving the code below as application.py allows me to run a process that when started shows a simple `QDialog` with a `QLabel`:

`python application.py`

While the process is running and dialog shown I would like to change the default title "somewhere over the rainbow" to something else. How to achieve it?

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
app = QApplication([])

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.label = QLabel('somewhere over the rainbow')
        self.layout().addWidget(self.label)
        self.show()

dialog = Dialog()
app.exec_()
```

### edited:

Below is an example of `QLabel`'s text set to a new string value "01011001001001110100100110":

[image]

Comment: Could you explain yourself better, would not it just be `self.label.setText("some text")` or what do you mean by title?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The post has been edited. Ideally the solution would allow anther process to emit a signal that could be catch by the application's event listening thread (Qt maybe?)

Comment: at what time do you want to change the text? the solution would not be self.label.setText("01011001001001110100100110")?

Comment: I would like to .setText("01011001001001110100100110") from another Python process. So the main `application` (the process that started the QDialog) could be "remotely controlled" from another Python application or a process.

Comment: then use `dialog.label.setText("01011001001001110100100110")`, 
if you do not provide a [mcve] I can not give you another help, 
I find it strange, you always provide good [mcve]

Comment: _I would like to .setText(...) from another Python process._ It's not a good idea that one _process_ calls methods of another _process_ and most OSes prohibits this. For this, [**IPC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) has been invented. Processes may communicate via files, pipes, shared memory (or memory mapped files), or even over network (which eliminates the constraint that both processes have to run on the same computer). Which of them to use is dependent on required speed, required robustness, etc... not to forget experience to implement them properly.

Comment: May be, this helps: [Python Doc.: 17.2. multiprocessing — Process-based parallelism](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). There are dedicated subsections for IPC: [17.2.1.3. Exchanging objects between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) and [17.2.1.4. Synchronization between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a working solution designed around `SocketServer`'s `TPCServer` and `BaseRequestHandler` Classes.

This implementation utilizes `QThread` Class.

[image]

`application.py`

```
import SocketServer

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

IP, PORT = '127.0.0.1', 62236

app = QApplication([])


class Emitter(QObject):
    signal = pyqtSignal(str)


class Handler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    emitter = Emitter()

    def handle(self):
        self.emitter.signal.emit(self.request.recv(1024))


class Thread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, target, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.target = target

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.target()


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)

        Handler.emitter.signal.connect(self.onEmit)
        self.server = SocketServer.TCPServer((IP, PORT), Handler)

        thread = Thread(target=self.server.handle_request)
        thread.start()

        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.label = QLabel('somewhere over the rainbow')
        self.layout().addWidget(self.label)
        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.server.server_close()
        event.accept()

    def onEmit(self, arg):
        self.label.setText(str(arg))


dialog = Dialog()
app.exec_()
```

`client.py`

```
import socket

IP, PORT = '127.0.0.1', 62236

def send(data):
    SOCKET = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    SOCKET.connect((IP, PORT))
    SOCKET.send(data)
    SOCKET.close()

for i in range(2, 1000):
    send('data %07d'%i)

send(raw_input("input:\t"))
```

With `threading.Thread` use `SocketServer.TCPServer.serve_forever` method instead of `SocketServer.TCPServer.handle_request`:

```
    import threading
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.server.serve_forever)
    thread.start()
```